# Calculate Length of Stay grouped by calendar months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregation

here is what I am dealing with:
I am given a table (Visit) with the following schema with sample data.

VISIT

```
VisitNo   Location  AdmissionDate  DischargeDate LengthOfStay
1         A         2012-04-28     2012-05-30     32
2         A         2012-04-20     2013-05-20     90
3         B         2012-04-01     2012-05-01     30
4         B         2012-05-01     2012-05-03     2
.....................................................
```

The requirements is that the returned data set is in the following structure. Total LengthOfStay of each location by Calendar Month(YYYYMM).

```
CalendarMonth  TotalLengthOfStayEachMonth(AdmissionToDate)  Location
201204          xxx                                          x
201205          yyyy                                         y
201206          zzzz                                         z
.........      ...............
```

The calculation of TotalLengthOfStayEachMonth is a little tricky. The days are counted since the AdmissionDate (admissionToDate), not literally 30 days per month basis.
For example, The first record in the VISIT table has;

- 2 days of stay in 201204
- 2+30 = 32 of days in 201205 and so forth...

Thanks in advance for your suggestions... FYI, we have hundreds of locations, thousand of vists and 5 years of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd prefer seeing your desired output, perhaps something like this will help get you started:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate, 112)  as CalendarMonth  ,
    SUM(DAY(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,AdmissionDate)+1,0)))-DAY(AdmissionDate)) as TotalLengthOfStayEachMonth,
    Location
FROM VISIT
GROUP BY CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate, 112), Location
```

Adding the Location will possibly give you duplicate CalendarMonths, but I assume that's ok.

EDIT --

I played around with this a little more as I realized some months would be missing dates if the DischargeDate was greater than 1 month over the AdmissionDate, and came up with this -- it uses the spt_values table:

```
select 
   CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)  as CalendarMonth,
   COUNT(*) Days,
   Location
from Visit t
inner join master..spt_values v
  on v.type='P' and v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, AdmissionDate, DischargeDate)
group by Location, CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)
order by CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112), Location
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cd3f/1).

-- Another Edit

While reviewing another answer, and not really understanding your situation (need that desired output), if your desired output is 2 days in April for your first record, then you just need to add  and v.number <> 0 to the join above -- easy enough, just wasn't sure what you were requesting.  This should be the simplest solution:

```
select 
   CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)  as CalendarMonth,
   COUNT(*) Days,
   Location
from Visit t
inner join master..spt_values v
  on v.type='P' and v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, AdmissionDate, DischargeDate) and v.number <> 0
group by Location, CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)
order by CONVERT(char(6), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112), Location
```

More [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cd3f/2).

Hope some of this helps.

Good luck.

Comment: Please read the question. This will only give the total number of days grouped by admission date. He wants to see the number of days in each month between admission date and discharge date

Comment: See edits -- This will produce a better performance than using a CTE.  Good luck.

Comment: Both solutions (Cha's and this one) work but this one produce much better performance. That's why I flagged this post as the accepted answer. Thanks to you both.

Comment: sgeddes, how would you modify this query if we wanted to group the data by calendar day, instead of month?

Answer (score 1):

This will do ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2afb1/7)):

```
with everyday (VisitNo, Location, dateOfStay)
AS (
  SELECT VisitNo, Location, dateadd(dd, 1, AdmissionDate)
  FROM VISIT
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.VisitNo, e.Location, dateadd(dd, 1, e.dateOfStay)
  FROM VISIT v INNER JOIN everyday e ON v.VisitNo = e.VisitNo and
    e.dateofStay < v.DischargeDate
  )
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), dateofstay, 121), VisitNo, Location, count(*) 
FROM everyday 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), dateofstay, 121), VisitNo, Location
ORDER BY 2,1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500);
```

If you want to group by Location only, use this one:

```
with everyday (VisitNo, Location, dateOfStay)
AS (
  SELECT VisitNo, Location, dateadd(dd, 1, AdmissionDate)
  FROM VISIT
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.VisitNo, e.Location, dateadd(dd, 1, e.dateOfStay)
  FROM VISIT v INNER JOIN everyday e ON v.VisitNo = e.VisitNo and
    e.dateofStay < v.DischargeDate
  )
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), dateofstay, 121), Location, count(*) 
FROM everyday 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), dateofstay, 121), Location
ORDER BY 2,1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 500);
```