# Break date range into calendar days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate-functions

Here is a business scenario with data: 
There is a hospital with several rooms in which patients are being admitted and discharged. You are asked to generate a report that displays the **'cumulative'** Length of Stay in day to day basis.

Source Table (Visit)

```
Visit#(int)   AdmissionDate(datetime)  DischargeDate(datetime)
1             2012-01-01               2012-01-05
2             2012-01-03               2012-01-06
3             2011-12-29               2012-01-04
```

The requirements is that the returned data set is in the following structure. You see, the length of stay grows incrementally with time. each record displays the number of patients in a given day and the cumulative length of stay (admission to date).

```
CalendarDay LenghthOfStay(day) NumberOfPatients
2011-12-29  1                  1
2011-12-30  2                  1
2011-12-31  3                  1
2012-01-01  5                  2
2012-01-02  7                  2
2012-01-03  10                 3
2012-01-04  13                 3
2012-01-05  15                 2
2012-01-06  16                 1
```

Thanks for your input, in advance.

Comment: I feel like I'm in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is very similar to your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432682/calculate-length-of-stay-grouped-by-calendar-months), and while this isn't 100% what you want, should help get you started:

```
select 
   CONVERT(char(10), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)  as CalendarDay,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(char(10), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112))  LenghthOfStay,
   COUNT(*) NumberOfPatients
from Visit t
inner join master..spt_values v
  on v.type='P' and v.number <= DATEDIFF(d, AdmissionDate, DischargeDate) 
group by CONVERT(char(10), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)
order by CONVERT(char(10), AdmissionDate+v.number, 112)
```

Dates are correct and patients are correct.  Not sure you can get the length of stay with pure SQL or not.

Good luck.